# CNTK: Reached the maximum number of allowed errors while reading the input file

Tags: artificial-intelligence, classification, cntk

I am developing a model that predict medical imaging for a Capstone project. I'm super new to CNTK (been using TF and Keras for a while) and I bumped into below error:

```
Reader from file train_data.ctf
Reader from file test_data.ctf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-01a27186472a>", line 6, in <module>
    exe_train_test(model, all_data = False)

  File "<ipython-input-8-65daea35bdc7>", line 8, in do_train_test
    train_test(read_train, read_test, model)

  File "<ipython-input-7-e044cc5a63e1>", line 32, in train_test
    data=train_reader.next_minibatch(mbatch_size, input_map = input_map)

  File "C:\Users\devg2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\internal\swig_helper.py", line 69, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\devg2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\io\__init__.py", line 329, in next_minibatch
    partition_index, device)

  File "C:\Users\devg2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 3143, in get_next_minibatch
    return _cntk_py.MinibatchSource_get_next_minibatch(self, *args)

RuntimeError: Reached the maximum number of allowed errors while reading the input file (train_data.ctf).

[CALL STACK]
    > Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::IDataReader::  SupportsDistributedMBRead
    - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::IDataReader::  SupportsDistributedMBRead (x6)
    - CreateCompositeDataReader (x5)
    - CNTK::TrainingParameterSchedule<unsigned __int64>::  GetMinibatchSize (x4)
```

Any guidance on whether I've missed something in my data inputs. Data is images in `.png` format.

Answer (score 1):

CNTK Nube here - However:

Lets say your Input stream configurations are like so:

```
0   |S0 178:1 |# BOS    |S1 14:1 |# flight  |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 479:1 |# i      |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 902:1 |# want       |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 851:1 |# to     |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 431:1 |# fly        |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 444:1 |# from       |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 266:1 |# boston     |S2 48:1 |# B-fromloc.city_name
0   |S0 240:1 |# at     |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 168:1 |# 838        |S2 35:1 |# B-depart_time.time
0   |S0 210:1 |# am     |S2 100:1 |# I-depart_time.time
0   |S0 215:1 |# and        |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 236:1 |# arrive     |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 482:1 |# in     |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 351:1 |# denver     |S2 78:1 |# B-toloc.city_name
0   |S0 240:1 |# at     |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 27:1 |# 1110        |S2 14:1 |# B-arrive_time.time
0   |S0 482:1 |# in     |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 827:1 |# the        |S2 128:1 |# O
0   |S0 606:1 |# morning        |S2 12:1 |# B-arrive_time.period_of_day
0   |S0 179:1 |# EOS        |S2 128:1 |# O
```

because I can not see an Input sample in your Question I have provided this from the ATIS Dataset.

Each Input and Output Stream Information must be configured with the correct dimensions and Axis. It must be configured like so:

```
cntk.io.MinibatchSource(cntk.io.CTFDeserializer(path, cntk.io.StreamDefs(
    query         = cntk.io.StreamDef(field='S0', shape=vocab_size,  is_sparse=True),
    intent_labels = cntk.io.StreamDef(field='S1', shape=num_intents, is_sparse=True),  # (used for intent classification variant)
    slot_labels   = cntk.io.StreamDef(field='S2', shape=num_labels,  is_sparse=True)
)), randomize=is_training, max_sweeps = cntk.io.INFINITELY_REPEAT if is_training else 1)
```

Streams S0, S1 and S2 must be configured with the correct Dimensions on the correct Axis.

The Model would look something like this:

```
Sequential([
    Label('input'),
    Embedding(emb_dim, name='embed'),
    Label('embedded_input'),
    Stabilizer(),
    Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim)),
    Stabilizer(),
    Label('hidden_representation'),
    Dense(num_labels, name='out_projection')
])
```

Although this example does not give you a direct answer for your .png example, it gives you a place to look, matching up the dimensions which CNTK is complaining about. I believe by the description of your question, if the above criteria is met, this will solve your problem.

This example is from the Microsoft Examples: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/LanguageUnderstanding/ATIS